# Manga where a guy drops his phone in water. After fixing it, he can buy items from another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manga where a young man drops his phone in water. He ends up putting it in rice and it turns out OK, only with a new app. It became an online store with items from another world.

First he buys are crochet needles to knot scarves to sell. Eventually he buys abilities such as being able to use lightning. Soon he found out that other people can use this app as well.

Comment: you have tagged this as an isekai, does this mean someone is traveling to/from the another world? The description doesn't seem to suggest that there is any travel between the worlds, just that a shop sells items/abilities 'from another world'.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

[*Miracle App Store*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45184736-miracle-app-store)

> Were stuck in our mundane lives. Dreaming of the lives we wish we had. But what if all your dreams can be solved with a few clicks. Would you take it?

It's much as you say. He drops the phone in water, retrieves it, and the eponymous app is on it when it recovers. He dries it with a hair dryer, not rice. And the first item he buys are "Perspective Sunglasses" that work a bit like stereotypical X-Ray Specs.

Found with a Google search for `magic phone app`, and filtering results by a particular manga-reading site via the `site:` keyword.

Comment: And it looks like it's not a manga.

Comment: Korean version, *manhwa* or the like transliteration.