# Manhwa/webtoon where the MC is poor, but has an app/system that makes him super good at doing certain jobs, which allows him to earn money

Tags: story-identification, manga

Read this before but can’t remember the name. He was able to learn how to knit scarves and earned money by selling them and making videos. It was a huge shock because the quality was good and he was super fast at knitting. He wears something that covers his face when making videos.

Comment: I'm unclear. Does the app make him good at knitting, or how he posts the videos? Or is this a special skill, like you often see in Isekai where he has *Hands of the Weaver* it the like that gives him 200% bonus to knitting?

Comment: The app makes him good at knitting. He’s like a pro at it and can make good quality scarfs in seconds. The video that he posted was shocking because he’s very fast at knitting and even experts were in shock due to how fast and good the scarf was. It’s not just knitting I think at one point he was making boxes or something? Sorry I don’t remember that much it’s been years since I read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be *Miracle App Store* as per [Manga where a guy drops his phone in water. After fixing it, he can buy items from another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233530/manga-where-a-guy-drops-his-phone-in-water-after-fixing-it-he-can-buy-items-fr/233532#233532)?

> Were stuck in our mundane lives. Dreaming of the lives we wish we had. But what if all your dreams can be solved with a few clicks. Would you take it?

### Contemplating buying the knitting needles

[image: Image mentioning the magic knitting needles] (click to enlarge)

### Masked Video

[image: Masked video] [image: Masked video 2] (click to enlarge)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the one that I was looking for